# three js directional light shadow

Tags: three.js, shadows

i am new to three js , i can able to generate the shadows using spot light but i receive unnecessary shadows too. what i need to do to remove the unwanted shadow .i need the shadows only for car and the wall and i need to remove the shadow like rectangle in the ground .[image]

my code is as follows

```
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            var light1 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xff00000);
            light1.position.set(200, 1200, 0);
            light1.target.position.set(0,0,0);    
            light1.shadowCameraVisible = true; 
            light1.castShadow = true;  
            light1.shadowDarkness = 0.8;
            light1.shadowCameraNear = 400;
            light1.shadowCameraFar = 1600;
            //light1.shadowCameraFov = 30;  

            light1.shadowCameraLeft = -750;
            light1.shadowCameraBottom =  -500;
            light1.shadowCameraRight = 1000;
            light1.shadowCameraTop = 600;


            var firstLight = new THREE.Object3D();
            firstLight.add(light1);
            scene.add(firstLight);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see this you want selective shadow of object for the performance tweak. 
The best you can do is for car model you have either *.obj,*.dae or which ever format loader you can load the object into scene via THREE.Object3D which has property "castShadow". Try this out:

```
var obj3D = new THREE.Object3D();
obj3D.add(/*content from loader*/);
obj3D.castShadow = true;
or
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh();
mesh.castShadow =true;
```

Enable or disable castShadow property with Mesh too.

I think this solve your problem